# Unkown opition while trying to use sed with a regular expression to replace a string

Tags: regex, linux, sed

I am trying to replace all the patterns in a file that are of the following form:

`> hello, test<` **by** `><link>hello, test</link><`

For this purpose I used the following command:

```
sed -i 's/>[a-zA-Z0-9_ ]*</><link>\1<link></g' finename.txt
```

- `>[a-zA-Z0-9_ ]*<`: find all the alphanumerical patterns between `><`
- `<link>\1<link>`: Replace them with `><link>pattern</link><`

However I am seeing the following error message

```
character 37. Reference \ 1 invalid in the right side of the control
```

What's wrong with the expression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `\1` references the first [capture group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refcapture.html) and you don't have any capture groups set up hence `\1` is invalid. What you want is:

```
$ echo ">hello, test<" | sed -r 's/>([a-zA-Z0-9,_ ]*)</><link>\1<link></g'
><link>hello, test<link><
```

The use of capture groups is part of extended regular expressions so you will need to use the `-r` argument. Also note in your example input you have a `,` but you don't include that character in your character class.

Comment: I have a questsion if I replace **>([a-zA-Z0-9,_ ]*)<** with **>(.*)<** will that make the regex better? I wont need to include the characters anymore

Comment: And concerning echo ">hello, test<" How can I change it in order to load directly from the file? what should I replace the **\1** with?

Comment: `>(.*)<`  will over-match `>([^<]*)<` will be better. Using `echo` in my answer was just a demonstration of the command working, you are already  reading from a file in your question, the only thing you need to change is the regular expression. Please note the `-i` flag overwrites the input file so be sure to test before running with `-i`.